# Exclude empty lines and comment lines

Tags: python, list, line

```
    import os


def countlines(start, lines=0, header=True, begin_start=None):
    if header:
        print('{:>10} |{:>10} | {:<20}'.format('ADDED', 'TOTAL', 'FILE'))
        print('{:->11}|{:->11}|{:->20}'.format('', '', ''))

    for thing in os.listdir(start):
        thing = os.path.join(start, thing)
        if os.path.isfile(thing):
            if thing.endswith('.py'):
                with open(thing, 'r') as f:
                    newlines = f.readlines()
                    newlines = list(filter(lambda l: l.replace(' ', '') not in ['\n', '\r\n'], newlines))
                    newlines = list(filter(lambda l: not l.startswith('#'), newlines))
                    newlines = len(newlines)
                    lines += newlines

                    if begin_start is not None:
                        reldir_of_thing = '.' + thing.replace(begin_start, '')
                    else:
                        reldir_of_thing = '.' + thing.replace(start, '')

                    print('{:>10} |{:>10} | {:<20}'.format(
                        newlines, lines, reldir_of_thing))

    for thing in os.listdir(start):
        thing = os.path.join(start, thing)
        if os.path.isdir(thing):
            lines = countlines(thing, lines, header=False, begin_start=start)

    return lines


countlines(r'/Documents/Python/')
```

If we take the standard Python file .main.py, then there are 4 lines of code in it. And he counts as 5. How to fix it?
How to properly set up a filter so that it does not count empty lines of code and comments?

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. Please show a MCVE: just the ~5 lines starting with `with`, a sample input with 3-4 lines, and the output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. You can modify your first `filter` condition**: `strip` the line, and then check that it isn't empty.

```
lambda l: l.replace(' ', '') not in ['\n', '\r\n']
```

becomes

```
lambda l: l.strip()
```

**2. `filter` takes any iterable**, so no need to convert it to lists every time - this is a waste because it forces two sets of iterations - one when you create the list, another when you filter it a second time. You could remove the calls to `list()` and only do it once after all your filtering is done. You can also use `filter` on the *file handle itself*, since the file handle `f` is an iterable that yields lines from the file in every iteration. This way, you only iterate over the entire file once.

```
newlines = filter(lambda l: l.strip(), f)
newlines = filter(lambda l: not l.strip().startswith('#'), newlines)
num_lines = len(list(newlines))
```

Note that I renamed the last variable, because a variable name should describe what it is

**3. You can combine both your filter condition into a single lambda**

```
lambda l: l.strip() and not l.strip().startswith('#')
```

or, if you have Python 3.8+,

```
lambda l: (l1 := l.strip()) and not l1.startswith('#')
```

This makes my point #2 about not `list`ing out the  above moot -

```
num_lines = len(list(filter(lambda l: (l1 := l.strip()) and l1.startswith('#'), f)))
```

With the following input, this gives the correct line count:

**file.py**:

```
print("Hello World")
# This is a comment
# The next line is blank

print("Bye")
```

```
>>> with open('file.py') as f:
...    num_lines = len(list(filter(lambda l: (l1 := l.strip()) and l1.startswith('#'), f)))
...    print(num_lines)

Out: 2
```